# Do I risk damage my usb port when connecting two laptop using regular phone cable (usb A to usb C)

Tags: usb, laptop, port, data-transfer

So my friends requested some files from my laptop, as he seat next to me, he hand me his phone charger cable (similar to what the picture shows)

[image]

I connected the usb A part to my laptop, he connect the usb C part to his laptop. There was no data transfer notification like I suspected, so I just unplug it and tell him he need to bring his flash drive.

I wonder will this damage my hardware/laptop ? This laptop is new and I really worried about any damage, I read that if you connect two usb A to usb A between laptop, there is a risk of electricity issues. I have search google for answer and have not found any conclusive answer.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to how micro-USB (regular versus "OTG") cables work, standards-compliant A-to-C cables will have a specific resistor on one of the additional pins on the 'C' end to indicate whether it should supply power or not. Your cable should be safe if it's correctly made. It's just that your OS on the 'C' end doesn't support behaving like a USB "device" that an 'A' port expects to talk to, so nothing useful happens.

(C-to-C cables also should be safe as they let both devices directly negotiate power supply with each other across those extra pins, but even C-to-C data transfer is still more complex than just having one end behave as a USB drive.)

Generally A-to-A cables would be unsafe because type-A ports have no such mechanism, they *always* supply power, so with a plain "passthrough" cable you'd have both laptops trying to power each other. There are *specific kinds* of A-to-A cables that are safe, such as the ones that actually have electronics in the middle, making them "A-to-chip-to-A" so both computers power the bridge chip and not each other.